# Wordpress sites doesn't load CSS & JS files on any browser on my device but loads all of them on other computers

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

My WP Websites loads all CSS & JS files in other computers but on some computers it doesn't using any browser.

i.e. I tried to load yesterday one of my WP websites and it was just plain text & images and none of the JS & CSS files were loaded (same in 3 browsers) but the computer next to me on the same network had no issue loading them. But today it loads perfectly on my computer but another WP website has this issue now.

Also admin login page does not load at all. ( The page isn’t redirecting properly )

[Page load with no css & js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXn7b.png)
[Page load with no css & js - Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vSBX.png)

Any ideas what causes this issue?

Thanks in advance

I tried to deactivate plugins, update/downgrade wordpress, change theme, remove theme, php upgrade, memory limit but no luck

Comment: Could you try clearing your cache on the machines the website doesn't load properly. 

What was the result when you changed to a default theme i.e twentytwentythree?

Is there anything within the server logs when the site doesn't load properly?

How are the sites hosted?

Comment: Sounds a bit like sporadic network/hosting issues... but it's hard to say without digging in a bit more... might be worth talking with your hosting support assuming you don't see issues like that with other websites from your location.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.